# How can I select the latest event for a given user in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

I have a table `[eventlog].[dbo].[USER_OPERATION]` with columns `[userID], [event_description], [event_date], [event_type], [eventID]`

`eventID` is unique for, well, every given event that can happen.

A given `UserID` is, of course, not unique for events (every user may have a lot of events associated with him) but is associated with a single individual user

What I want is to create a query that would give me a list which only has the *latest* event for every user (that is to say, every `UserID`) and its associated info (the `event_type`, `eventID` and `event_description` of a given specific event).

To illustrate:

When performing

```
SELECT * 
FROM [eventlog].[dbo].[USER_OPERATION] 
ORDER BY userID ASC
```

I get something along the lines of

```
|====================================================================================|
|  eventID  |  userID  |        event_description        |  event_date  | event_type |
|           |          |                                 |              |            |
|   123     |    2     |  USER 2 broke something         |  03.11.11    |   CRASH    |
|   391     |    2     |  USER 2 filed a complaint       |  30.04.10    |  COMPLAINT |
|   392     |    2     |  USER 2 has bought beer         |  31.10.09    |  PURCHASE  |
|   32      |    3     |  USER 3 broke something         |  22.10.11    |   CRASH    |
|   568     |    4     |  USER 4 has requested support   |  05.12.11    |  SUPP_REQ  |
|   691     |    4     |  USER 4 has bought beer         |  01.12.10    |  PURCHASE  |
|   81      |    4     |  USER 4 updated personal data   |  17.07.11    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|   141     |    5     |  USER 5 has bought beer         |  16.08.11    |  PURCHASE  |
|   142     |    5     |  USER 5 broke something         |  16.08.11    |   CRASH    |
|   269     |    6     |  USER 6 updated personal data   |  27.01.12    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|   845     |    7     |  USER 7 updated personal data   |  27.01.12    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|           |          |                                 |              |            |
|====================================================================================|
```

As you can see, some users have multiple events with different dates associated with them.

What I want is a query that will show me a list of users and what was the most recent date users had an event on (the output would, essentially, be a table which lists each users once, and shows the most recent event associated with each user, and associated event_description, event_date and event_type info).

Let's call such a query result "Recent Event Table".

**Do note the "unusual condition" of User 5 (UserID 5) who broke something and bought beer at the same date.**

In such cases, I don't care WHICH of the two same-day events would go into the "Recent Event Table", it can be picked by random or whatever (though I would still would need the associated event_description and event_type info).

**Ideally**, the result would look like this (for same set of users as above):

```
|====================================================================================|
|  eventID  |  userID  |        event_description        |  event_date  | event_type |
|           |          |                                 |              |            |
|   123     |    2     |  USER 2 broke something         |  03.11.11    |   CRASH    |
|   32      |    3     |  USER 3 broke something         |  22.10.11    |   CRASH    |
|   568     |    4     |  USER 4 has requested support   |  05.12.11    |  SUPP_REQ  |
|   141     |    5     |  USER 5 has bought beer         |  16.08.11    |  PURCHASE  |
|   269     |    6     |  USER 6 updated personal data   |  27.01.12    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|   845     |    7     |  USER 7 updated personal data   |  27.01.12    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|           |          |                                 |              |            |
|====================================================================================|
```

If there is no way to just *"pick any one of the two randomly or per some rule"* for such "date-dupes" as User 5, having two entries in the "Recent Event Table" would be acceptable for such special cases, since they are very rare and I can handle them manually.

In such (a little bit less fortunate) case the "Recent Event Table" would look like

```
|====================================================================================|
|  eventID  |  userID  |        event_description        |  event_date  | event_type |
|           |          |                                 |              |            |
|   123     |    2     |  USER 2 broke something         |  03.11.11    |   CRASH    |
|   32      |    3     |  USER 3 broke something         |  22.10.11    |   CRASH    |
|   568     |    4     |  USER 4 has requested support   |  05.12.11    |  SUPP_REQ  |
|   141     |    5     |  USER 5 has bought beer         |  16.08.11    |  PURCHASE  |
|   142     |    5     |  USER 5 broke something         |  16.08.11    |   CRASH    |
|   269     |    6     |  USER 6 updated personal data   |  27.01.12    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|   845     |    7     |  USER 7 updated personal data   |  27.01.12    |  PDAT_UPD  |
|           |          |                                 |              |            |
|====================================================================================|
```

Which is also acceptable (but would need a bit additional pruning later).

So, to summarize my question, is it possible to construct such a Microsoft SQL query that would give me a Recent Event Table along the lines of what was described above ?

Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: Why did you tagged it with mysql tag??

Comment: Sorry, a brain-fart of mine. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE (*Common Table Expression*) combined with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  
       *,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID 
                                   ORDER BY event_date DESC, event_id DESC)
    FROM [eventlog].[dbo].[USER_OPERATION] 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This "partitions" your data into groups - one each for every `UserID` - and then sorts the events inside that group of data by `event_date DESC` and `event_id DESC`) and numbers them - the most recent entry (for each user) gets `RowNum = 1` - so just select those from the CTE and you're done!

Comment: Wow. As far as I can tell (double-checking now), it does exactly what is needed (well, I tried the one with just "ORDER BY event_date DESC"). Seems fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, marc_s, what's the person of sorting by event_id after sorting by event_date? (so far, it appears to work out fine both ways, as far as I can tell...)

Comment: @Lone_passerby: to handle your specific special case (UserID = 5) - there are multiple events with the same  `event_date` - so sorting just by `event_date` isn't enough....

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @USER_OPERATION table 
(
eventID int,
userID int,
event_description nvarchar(250),
event_date date,
event_type nvarchar(250)
)
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (123,2,'USER 2 broke something','11/03/11','CRASH')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (391,2,'USER 2 filled a complaint','04/30/10','COMPLAINT')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (392,2,'USER 2 bought beer','10/31/09','PURCHASE')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (32,3,'USER 3 broke something','10/22/11','CRASH')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (568,4,'USER 4 has requested support','12/05/11','SUPP_REQ')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (691,4,'USER 4 has bought beer','12/01/10','PURCHASE ')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (81,4,'USER 4 updated personal data','07/17/11','PDAT_UPD ')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (141,5,' USER 5 has bought beer','08/16/11','PURCHASE')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (142,5,' USER 5 broke something','08/16/11','CRASH')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (269,6,'USER 6 updated personal data','01/27/12','PDAT_UPD')
Insert into @USER_OPERATION values  (845,7,'USER 7 updated personal data ','01/27/12','PDAT_UPD')


SELECT * FROM @USER_OPERATION AS userOp INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT userID, (SELECT Top 1 eventID FROM @USER_OPERATION a WHERE a.userID  =B.userID ORDER BY event_date DESC)as eventID
from @USER_OPERATION AS B) as tbl 
ON userOp.userID =tbl.userID and userOp.eventID =tbl.eventID
```